# Exporting map containing raster layer with vector field symbology ends up with partially rendered symbology from ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, export, arcgis-10.3, rendering

After exporting a map in ArcMap (ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop) which contains several raster and vector layers including one raster layer resembling flow direction of ice, the output file (tried JPG, PNG and PDF so far) always contains lines in which the Vector Field Symbology is only partially rendered.

In this very example it seems like a pattern of four perfectly fine rendered symbols, followed by four lines which a partially rendered (repeating pattern).

Screenshot in ArcMap Layout View:

[image]

Crop of exported map:

[image: crop of map export]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried *printing* to pdf rather than *exporting*? Exactly what kind of symbology is it (marker, character, etc.)?

Comment: Have you tried checking/repairing geometry on any polygon feature classes being displayed?

Comment: @ChrisW: Tried printing to PDF (CutePDF Writer 600 dpi), same problem!  I used Single Arrow -> Type: Character Marker Symbol -> Font ESRI Arrowhead.

Comment: have you used transparency in any of the layers?

Comment: I might have... it's been over 2 years since I posted this, can't remember! But I'm pretty sure I did, actually! You can see the relief layer (greyscale) through the speed layer (colors).